# How does facebook do this onkeyup and onchange at the password change?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I noticed that in the Facebook the change passwords, they have this nice alert at the bottom telling you that the passwords do not match or if the confirm password is too short.

However, when I use the firebug, I do not see any `onkeyup` or `onchange`.

And they did it very well regardless of whether I type or if I copy a string and paste, it will trigger the (I suspect JavaScript) validation.

How do they do it? More importantly I want to copy the way they do it.

Here is the firebug I saw at their HTML.

```
<tr class="password confirm_password">
    <td class="label">
        Confirm Password:
        <br/>
        <small>(required)</small>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="confirm_password" class="inputpassword" type="password" value="" name="confirm_password"/>
        <div id="confirm_password_match_display" class="tips">
            <span class="short_pass">Passwords do not match</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The weird thing is the span `class="short_pass"` appears only when it is triggered. How do they do it? And notice that they input tags have no `onkeyup` or `onchange` properties.

Comment: Check the external javascript files. You can define functions that bind to elements of the dom outside of the html tags, which would explain why you don't see the javascript there.

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to subscribe to events such as `onkeyup`, and `onkeychange` from JavaScript and not embed the event listeners as attributes in the elements themselves. This gives a good separation of logic and content. Facebook most likely has some external (or internal) JavaScript code that subscribes to the `onkeyup`, `onkeypress`, and `onblur` events of its input fields.

If you want to learn how this works, I suggest you read QuirksMode.org's [Introduction to Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html), and [Advanced Event Registration Models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html). Because of the differences between IE's model and the standard, you're better off using a JavaScript library to do this work for you.

A few examples are [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event), and [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/node/134) (and there are more that I can't think of at the moment). I suggest you pick a framework, and become familiar with it. It will make JavaScript development much easier.

Here is some working example code in jQuery that you can use to get up and running very quickly. A full working example can be found here: http://jsbin.com/obama. If you want it done "right", you should use a validation framework that handles the logic for you. Here's an [example of a working jQuery validation framework](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/), and here is [the plugin it was written in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

```
(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#password").blur(function() {

    });

    function validatePasswordsMatch() {
        var $pwd = $("#password");
        var $confirm = $("#confirmPassword");
        if ($pwd.val().length > 0 && $confirm.val().length > 0 && $pwd.val() != $confirm.val()) {
            $("#match").text("Passwords do not match.");
            $confirm.keyup(validatePasswordsMatch);
            $pwd.keyup(validatePasswordsMatch);
            console.log('alert bad');
        } else {
            $("#match").text("");
            console.log('alert');
            $confirm.unbind('keyup', validatePasswordsMatch);
            $pwd.unbind('keyup', validatePasswordsMatch);
        }
    }

    function validatePasswordLength() {
        var $pwd = $("#password");
        if ($pwd.val().length < 6) {
            $("#lengthMsg").text("Password does not meet length requirement.");
            // Bind to keypress so the validator re-validates as the user types when the text box gains focus.
            $pwd.keypress(validatePasswordLength);
        } else {
            $("#lengthMsg").text("");
            $pwd.unbind('keypress', validatePasswordLength);
        }
    }

    $("#password").blur(validatePasswordLength).blur(validatePasswordsMatch);
    $("#confirmPassword").blur(validatePasswordsMatch);

});
})();
```

Comment: hi please forgive me if i sound rude. i am kinda short in time. i can understand what you mean by separating logic and content. i do not have the time to understand jQuery, YUI, etc. is there a resource that i can look at and do this in a quick and dirty way fast?

Comment: sorry i need a bit of hand holding. i apologise.

Comment: keisimone, you can find plenty of examples of handling key events here on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+key+events.